# Ruby Module Syntax Error

Tags: ruby, module

I'm having a few issues understanding Modules in Ruby, specifically how variables are stored. The trouble I'm having is this;

```
module Mod

  MODE = 0

  def Mod.beginSearch
    MODE = 2
  end
end
```

I'm getting a syntax error, which is pointing me to the line "MODE = 2". My environment won't tell me any more than that, so I have no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using instance variables (with `@`):

```
module Mod
  def Mod.begin_search
    # set @mode to 2. Instance variables are preserved among methods.
    @mode = 2
  end
  def Mod.mode
    # set @mode to 0 if it's not initialized yet.
    @mode ||= 0
  end
  def Mod.time_for_search
    # use Mod.mode to get @mode, granted it's set (0, 2 or whatever)
    mode == 2
  end
end

# Testing...
puts Mod.mode
#=> 0

puts Mod.time_for_search
#=> false

Mod.begin_search
puts Mod.mode
#=> 2

puts Mod.time_for_search
#=> true
```

Comment: That's got it! Works perfectly, thanks for the help, man! Quick question, though... What does the "||=" operator do? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: It means `@mode = @mode || 0`, what is: if `@mode` is evaluated as `true`, take it; else (i.e., when it's `false` or `nil`), take the next value (`0` in the case). An unitialized instance variable is assumed to be `nil` on first reference. That means: if `@mode` is not set, take the value `0`; if it's set (e.g.: `0`, `2` or whatever), maintain its value.

Answer (score 1):

A variable starting with a capital is a constant in Ruby. You *can* reassign a constant, but it will cause Ruby to issue a warning. But not inside a method:

"Ruby assumes that methods are intended to be invoked more then once; if you could assign to a constant in a method, that method would issue warnings on every invocation after the first. So, this is simply not allowed." (The Ruby Programming Language, D. Flanagan & Y. Matsumoto, 2008, p.94)

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, variables that being with a capital letter are constant. You set `MODE` to 0, but then in the method `beginSearch`, you set `MODE` to 2, which you can't do as `MODE` is a constant.

Comment: `MODE=1; MODE=2`is valid Ruby but you'll get a warning.

Comment: @steenslag: This particular construct, however, *does* result in a syntax error.

Comment: Indeed. That is because you can reassign a constant, but not inside a method.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise about the constants thing. I changed them all into variables, because that's what they are, really. However, it's led to another problem. I don't seem to be able to read the variables from within a method in the module. I have another method called "time_for_search" which returns true if mode == 2. Although the project compiles now, when it runs it says that a "NameError Occured. undefined local variable or method 'mode' for Mod:Module". Sorry if this is a completely rookie error, I'm probably missing something obvious.